# How to plot a graph in css with both x and y values

Tags: html, css, web, visualization

Here I am trying to plot a graph in css. Finally I ended up with this output with only one value. But I need to plot the values for both x and y axis. Like a scattered graph.
How can I do that. I shouldnot use any library or any other plugins restricted only to HTML and CSS. Can anyone please help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700);
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;   
}
body {
  background: #1f253d;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

 
  .font-color {
    color: #9099b7;
  }
    .block {
      margin: 25px 25px 0 0;
      background: #394264;
      border-radius: 5px;
      float: left;
      width: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
   
      .line-chart-block, {
        height: 400px;
      }
       .line-chart {
          height: 200px;
          background: #11a8ab;
        }

.graph {
  padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80%;
}
.graph span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3rem;
  left: 2rem;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.graph span > span {
  left: 100%; bottom: 0;
}
[data-value='25'] {width: 95px; transform: rotate(-45deg);}
[data-value='8'] {width: 24px; transform: rotate(65deg);}
[data-value='13'] {width: 39px; transform: rotate(-45deg);}
[data-value='5'] {width: 15px; transform: rotate(50deg);}
[data-value='23'] {width: 69px; transform: rotate(-70deg);}
[data-value='12'] {width: 36px; transform: rotate(75deg);}
[data-value='15'] {width: 45px; transform: rotate(-45deg);}

[data-value]:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: -3px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

[class^='plot-'] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0 2rem;
  height: 80%;
}
.plot-x {
  height: 2.5rem;
}
.plot-y li {
  height: 25%;
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
}
[data-plotY]:before {
  content: attr(data-plotY);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: -2.5rem;
  top: -.5rem;
} 
.plot-x li {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head> <title> graph </title>
<h1 style="color:#ffffff">Linear Graph</h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="graph.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- plotting graph-->
  <div class="line-chart-block block">
    <div class="line-chart">
      <div class='graph'>
        <ul class='plot-y'>
          
          <li data-plotY='30'></li>
          <li data-plotY='20'></li>
          <li data-plotY='10'></li>
          <li data-plotY='0'></li>
          
        </ul>
        <ul class='plot-x'>
          <li>10</li>
          <li>20</li>
          <li> 30</li>
        </ul>
        <span data-value='25'>
           <span data-value='8'>
             <span data-value='13'>
               <span data-value='5'>   
                 <span data-value='23'>   
                 <span data-value='12'>
                     <span data-value='15'>
                     </span></span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your graph is already in x and y axis.

Comment: @hunzaboy I have to give both the x and y axis values. In that snippet I have only one value.

Comment: You are giving the y values using the data-plotY . Any circle you have in the graph has both the values. Let me know if i am missing anything here.

Comment: @hunzaboy I have taken only one value for plotting. But I need to plot with 2 values like (x,y)=(10,20)